# How to use <a4j:jsFunction><a4j:actionparam>

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function myfunc() {
         var param = 4;
         alert("OK");
      }
</script>
```

I call the function like this:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="myfunc">
    <a4j:actionparam name="param" assignTo="#{MyBean.myfield}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

But it does not work. In what may be the reason?

Comment: what does not work? Where are you calling myfunc() from? The script tag is not properly closed, maybe that is a problem: should be `</script>`.

Comment: Well, the function needs to be called somehow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You misunderstood the purpose of `<a4j:jsFunction>`. It **autogenerates** a JavaScript function which you can then call from any JavaScript code in your view.

Your example,

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="myfunc">
    <a4j:actionparam name="param" assignTo="#{MyBean.myfield}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

will *autogenerate* the following function

```
<script>
    function myfunc(param) {
        // Here some specific JSF Ajax script which assigns "param"
        // to a managed bean property #{MyBean.myfield}
    }
</script>
```

You do *not* need to define it yourself. You only need to *invoke* it yourself from some JavaScript code elsewhere. For example,

```
<span onclick="myfunc(4)">click here to set 4 in MyBean.myfield</span>
```

or

```
<script>
    function someOtherFunction() {
        var param = 4;
        myfunc(param);
    }
</script>
```

which is in turn to be used like

```
<span onclick="someOtherFunction()">click here to call someOtherFunction() which will in turn set 4 in MyBean.myfield</span>
```

#### See also:

- [`<a4j:jsFunction>` component reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jjsFunction)
- [`<a4j:jsFunction>` showcase example](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=jsFunction&skin=blueSky)

Answer (score 4):

```
<a4j:jsFunction
```

is not used to call an function, it is used to define an function.

So, if MyBean.myfield is an int-field you can set the value 2 using:

```
<script>myfunc(2);</sript>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of different ways to call that function.

Two you will find particularly useful are:

**This:**

```
<body onload="myfunc();">
```

Example: http://ultimatemmo.webege.com/Test.html

**and this:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunc();">Click here to execute function</a>
```

Example: http://ultimatemmo.webege.com/Test2.html

**Edit:** added examples.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Comment: The second part of the question wasn't there when I answered, I thought he was asking how to call his function

Answer (score 0):

According you snippet of code, you have never called your function. Add `myfunc();` within your script tag.